# Why is my else statement triggering sometimes but not always?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am attempting to make an adventure game with some combat in it.

However, the

```
else:
    print("The werewolf took " + str(damage) + " damage. " + str(werewolf_health) + " health remains.")
```

trigger (and the code beneath it) only triggers sometimes. Can you help me out with why?

This is the code:

```
def attack():
    werewolf_health = 100
    user_health = 100
    while werewolf_health > 0:
        attack = input(">").upper()
        if "ATTACK" in attack:
            damage = rand_int()
            damage2 = rand_int_werewolf()
            if damage == 20:
                print(random.choice(sword_crit))
                damage = damage * 1.5
                werewolf_health = werewolf_health - damage
                print("The werewolf took " + str(damage) + " damage. " + str(werewolf_health) + " health remains.")
                if werewolf_health <= 0:
                    print(random.choice(werewolf_death))
                    resolution()
            elif 17 <= damage <= 19:
                print(random.choice(sword_above_avg))
                werewolf_health = werewolf_health - damage
                print("The werewolf took " + str(damage) + " damage. " + str(werewolf_health) + " health remains.")
                if werewolf_health <= 0:
                    print(random.choice(werewolf_death))
                    resolution()
            elif 6 <= damage <= 16:
                print(random.choice(sword_avg))
                werewolf_health = werewolf_health - damage
                if werewolf_health <= 0:
                    print(random.choice(werewolf_death))
                    resolution()
                else:
                    print("The werewolf took " + str(damage) + " damage. " + str(werewolf_health) + " health remains.")
                    damage2 = rand_int_werewolf()
                    if damage2 == 20:
                        print(random.choice(werewolf_crit))
                        damage2 = damage2 * 1.5
                        user_health = user_health - damage2
                        print("You take " + str(damage2) + " damage. " + "Your health drops to " + str(
                            user_health) + ".")
```

Comment: could it be the indentation of your else? Because how it stands, is your else is only triggering IF elif 6 <= damage <= 16: triggers also. Because you have your main IF statement and then Elif statements, but if you want the ELSE to be whatever the ELIFs arent you have to have it line up with the rest of the elif statements, if I understand correctly

Comment: @troy But that is what Im going for, for elif 6 <= damage <= 16 to trigger, then if the werewolf_health is less than or equal to 0 resolution():. And only then, if the werewolf_health is still "alive" will the werewolf attack trigger. But it doesn't trigger for some reason. Even if the werewolf_health is still over 0

Comment: maybe `damage` is `< 6` or `> 20`?

Comment: Where is the variable for werewolf_health being stored? Maybe the var werewolf_health isn't updating as you intended.